# Trouble translating jQuery to Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm playing around with animating different elements at the moment. Specifically, an off-screen navigation bar that appears when a button is pressed. I originally wrote it in jQuery, as that was what I was learning at the time and it worked perfectly, but now wish to rewrite it in vanilla JS and can't seem to get it to work.

This is the jQuery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#hambBtn').click(function(){
       $('#hambBtn span').toggleClass('active')
       $('#menuWrapper').toggleClass('active')
     })
 })
```

So far the vanilla JS looks like this:

```
      const hamb-btn = document.querySelector("#hambBtn");

      hamb-btn.addEventListener("click", animateHamb);

      function animateHamb(){
          const hambSpan = document.querySelector(".hamb-btn");
          const menuWrap = document.querySelector("#menuWrapper");
          hambSpan.classList.toggle("active");
          menuWrap.classList.toggle("active");
      }
```

Can anyone explain if there is anything that the jQuery code is doing that the vanilla JS isn't so that I can correct it?

Comment: You can't use hyphen to name constants or variables, so **const hamb-btn ...** is wrong, you can use underscore (hamb_btn) or camelcalse (hambBtn) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You've converted some of the code correctly, however you've just created a function, while the JQuery sets up a function to automatically be called when the DOM is loaded. A more precise line for line conversion would be:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  document.getElementById('hambBtn').addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector('#hambBtn span').classList.toggle('active');
    document.getElementById('menuWrapper').classList.toggle('active');
  });
});
```